# iFrame embeded document editor blinks in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-drive-api

I use Google Drive API for adding ability to edit user uploaded files by sending them to user's Drive and opening a link in iFrame. It was working cool, till some recent updates on Drive. After that updates iFrame start to "blink" when focused and have a cursor moved in it. But, this only happens in Chrome.

UPD:
I've discovered that it happens because of transition: opacity .13s ease-in 0; applied to "kix-cursor-caret".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this CSS to your page, as suggested [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/fix-chrome-animation-flash-bug/):

```
body {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
```

I've had the same problem for CSS3 animations within iframes, and this CSS solved it. There's currently [an open Chromium bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=339893) about iframe flickering, which you might want to follow if the above doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, they fixed this bug in current version (35)